# Connect a Thomson 585 wireless router

Tags: wireless-router

I have received a Thomson wirelesss router, connected it (shows a broadband light) but when I try to open Internet Explorer to input the username and password, the welcome page does not appear. Should I be able to access the router whilst not connected to the internet, via 192.168.1.1 ?

Answer (score 1):

The IP address for the device is `10.0.0.138`. The default user is "admin".

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can connect directly to router via it's default IP. For Thompson I think it's 192.168.1.254

default username and password

username: administration
password: (none, just leave it blank)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this: Start > Run > Fill in the box with "cmd" (without the quotation marks) > type "ipconfig /all" (without the quotation marks) and look for "Standard Gateway", the IP of your router is next to it.